# Using cast() or ddply() to summarise the mean for two continuous variables in one dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, casting, reshape, plyr

The data (below) has two columns named "Date" and "Independent Variable (IV)" containing factors, plus two extra columns called "Independent_value" and "Sapflow" containing continuous values.

Column Descriptions:

Date = measurements of the independent variables over 5 months (June-October).

Independent Variable = 3 independent variables (i.e temperature, humidity, and radiation).

Independent Value = represents readings of temperature, radiation, and humidity over daily time steps from June to October.

Sapflow (dependent variable) =  sapflow rates in tree species recorded over daily time steps from June to October and how the independent variables may affect these rates of sapflow.

**Goal**

In this instance, I would like to summarise the data (found below) by group (i.e. Date and Independent variable) using either ***cast()*** or ***ddply()*** to produce a new data frame showing the mean recorded value of each independent variable (temperature, humidity, and radiation) per month and the mean rate of sapflow for independent variables per month in the following format:-

*Key

*IV = independent variable (i.e.Temperature, Humidity, and Radation)

*Mean_IV = the mean of the independent variable

*Mean_Sapflow (dependent variable) = the mean sapflow rate per month per independent variable

```
 Date      IV           Mean_IV   Mean_Sapflow
1 June     Humidity     19.67     14.97
2 June     Humidity     18.82     16.31
3 June     Humidity     20.38     17.52
4 June     Humidity     14.94      7.45
5 June     Humidity     12.92     12.18
6 June     Humidity     15.28     15.82
```

**Problem:**

I have tried using **ddply()** and **cast()** and I cannot produce the dataframe format shown above. If anyone can help, I would be deeply appreciative.

***ddply**

```
library(plyr)

summarised_Sapflow<-ddply(Sapflow_new, c("Date", "Independent_Variable"), summarise,
                      N=length(Independent_Value),
                    mean("Independent Value","Sapflow"))
```

The output is a series of warnings:

```
  Warning messages:
  1: In mean.default("Independent Value", "Sapflow") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
  2: In mean.default("Independent Value", "Sapflow") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
  3: In mean.default("Independent Value", "Sapflow") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

**cast()**

```
library(reshape)

Sapflow.Summary<-cast(Sapflow_new, 
                 Date~Independent_Variable, mean, 
                 value=c('Independent_Value','Sapflow'))
```

This output is very close to my goal but mean sapflow is missing and the months contained in the "Date" are organised in the wrong order because the arrangment of my code is probably incorrect.

```
           Date       Humidity Radiation Temperature
         1 August     18.38968  178.9806    71.73355
         2 July       21.80065  270.9065    61.33065
         3 June       17.60733  263.6733    70.56133
         4 October    11.34867   93.6000    81.74300
         5 September  14.82200  152.2333    72.21367
```

**Data:**

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("August", "July", "June", "October", 
"September"
 ), class = "factor"), Independent_Variable = 
structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Humidity", 
"Radiation", 
"Temperature"), class = "factor"), Independent_Value = 
c(19.67, 
18.82, 20.38, 14.94, 12.92, 15.28, 15.12, 16.05, 15.19, 
16.67, 
18.69, 14.61, 16.71, 17.35, 16.98, 15.44, 15.21, 18.62, 
20.11, 
18.64, 15.66, 17.2, 18.21, 19.32, 23.02, 21.69, 18.03, 
18.46, 
18.45, 20.78, 23.04, 22.05, 19.71, 20.59, 24.89, 23.34, 
24.7, 
24.2, 22.43, 18.21, 17.66, 18.23, 20.36, 22.83, 23.52, 
22.88, 
19.59, 21.51, 22.25, 21.47, 22.03, 22.51, 25.54, 24.01, 
24.28, 
26.21, 23.72, 17.63, 17.27, 19.19, 19.97, 19.84, 22.78, 
24.46, 
23.05, 23.31, 24.75, 23.23, 18.91, 15.56, 13.51, 15.8, 
17.67, 
19.18, 18.93, 20.05, 17.1, 16.87, 18.77, 20.49, 21.5, 
18.04, 
18.82, 17.38, 13.05, 13.13, 13.48, 16.32, 16.74, 16.11, 
15.77, 
15.48, 18.17, 18.16, 18.44, 16.63, 16.64, 14.47, 13.07, 
14.14, 
 17.27, 16.71, 18.22, 12.9, 13.95, 14.7, 15.78, 17.52, 
19.66, 
18.87, 18.07, 16.4, 12.92, 10.57, 10.04, 9.78, 10.24, 
 14.25, 
15.92, 11.59, 9.25, 10.33, 11.22, 15.03, 13.67, 14.26, 
15.42, 
8.34, 8.56, 12.37, 14.38, 15.47, 16.4, 17.15, 20.05, 
11.08, 10.63, 
14.34, 13.27, 9.33, 8.1, 10.95, 12.79, 8.64, 11.42, 
12.12, 9.91, 
7.86, 3.51, 4.97, 3.63, 5.59, 85.07, 79.72, 72.83, 90.1, 
83.02, 
 73.34, 77.11, 74.79, 81.66, 77.71, 66.14, 78.15, 69.33, 
68.13, 
60.31, 69.47, 81.86, 78.63, 77.69, 77.56, 52.88, 53.32, 
53.74, 
55.85, 49.56, 55.3, 69.25, 74.96, 69.29, 60.07, 54.31, 
48.6, 
55.73, 56.74, 47.66, 60.51, 55.64, 58.39, 63.8, 63.16, 
73.65, 
71.08, 64.34, 60.1, 51.61, 54.87, 58.23, 52.49, 52.56, 
59.64, 
67.85, 64.42, 60.08, 59.71, 57.12, 58.7, 68.85, 72.44, 
89.13, 
77.67, 62.17, 61.3, 63.58, 66.26, 60.09, 56.63, 53.11, 
59.84, 
60.06, 80.76, 79.51, 73.96, 84.58, 78.77, 71.65, 72.59, 
77.52, 
69.04, 78.26, 77.22, 73.75, 81.95, 82.04, 78.14, 73.41, 
72.76, 
90.68, 74.24, 71.3, 74.4, 60.26, 66.08, 65.18, 57.17, 
66.88, 
75.53, 71.52, 74.97, 66.02, 78.06, 73.58, 68.18, 83.55, 
80.4, 
66.28, 72.32, 72.39, 77.74, 69.81, 74.21, 77.37, 88.28, 
65.33, 
87.54, 80.49, 69.58, 68.18, 69.25, 60.06, 66.38, 68.51, 
71.65, 
63.29, 76.63, 80.46, 85.56, 81.25, 94.48, 73.87, 76.8, 
72.83, 
77.55, 81.5, 77.7, 75.79, 94.38, 99.55, 94.14, 87.29, 
84.81, 
82.63, 85.27, 84.52, 71.13, 76.28, 78.06, 82.83, 75.18, 
83.8, 
85.38, 84, 85.33, 197.8, 195.5, 288, 72, 160.5, 337.1, 
176.9, 
242.3, 189.4, 295.7, 363.2, 158, 290, 251.2, 297.3, 
192.6, 163.5, 
274.5, 210.7, 243.4, 287.4, 375.7, 290.5, 336.4, 361.6, 
369.2, 
 302.6, 295.2, 348.5, 343.5, 327.6, 358.9, 358.6, 288.9, 
 325.6, 
307.8, 321.3, 321.5, 280.6, 264.9, 253, 279.5, 318.1, 
285.1, 
330.8, 252, 201, 229.9, 259.3, 230.4, 265.5, 214.1, 307, 
311.1, 
282.5, 256.9, 227.2, 263.4, 68.2, 130.8, 276.6, 299.2, 
276.5, 
243.9, 291, 289.3, 290.6, 259.6, 220.5, 72.7, 158.9, 
233.8, 105.9, 
164.2, 168.1, 188.7, 120.1, 217.7, 111.2, 114.7, 143.6, 
55.2, 
108.5, 162.2, 185, 197.7, 54.1, 126.3, 111.2, 135.4, 
228.3, 214.3, 
 240.1, 247.6, 173, 172.4, 131.9, 149.4, 203.1, 92.3, 
168.5, 146.6, 
65.9, 103.6, 200.2, 131.3, 183.5, 128.3, 140.6, 124.1, 
125.9, 
75.8, 173.2, 47.9, 111.7, 205.8, 188.3, 175.6, 193.7, 
170.4, 
188.3, 108, 171.1, 59.5, 87.7, 142.2, 111.8, 26.3, 
129.9, 103.1, 
158.7, 147.9, 109.8, 67.8, 106.6, 12.3, 15.8, 53, 63.4, 
86.2, 
123.3, 112.9, 128.2, 141.9, 81.6, 102, 86.8, 83.9, 50, 
96.8, 
100.5, 47), Sapflow = c(14.97, 16.31, 17.52, 7.45, 
 12.18, 15.82, 
 11.79, 14.45, 10.95, 13.62, 16.28, 11.42, 16.13, 15.09, 
 17.28, 
 14.43, 11.7, 16.06, 17.66, 16.33, 17.79, 18.58, 19.41, 
 19.8, 
 21.63, 21.35, 17.81, 17.56, 19.37, 21.27, 23.26, 23.67, 
  22.64, 
 21.85, 24.81, 22.36, 24.72, 23.87, 23.67, 22.01, 19.23, 
 19.92, 
 21.99, 23.6, 24.9, 24.46, 22.22, 23.95, 24.81, 23.88, 
 22.98, 
 24.47, 26.09, 25.97, 25.82, 26.24, 25.09, 22, 16.91, 
 21.35, 25.32, 
  25.76, 26.38, 25.78, 25.77, 25.15, 26.29, 26.22, 
  24.59, 18.26, 
 18.91, 21.57, 21.37, 21.29, 23.96, 24.85, 21.02, 23.05, 
 22.69, 
 23.9, 25.24, 25.4, 23.19, 22.8, 22.08, 21.86, 13.82, 
 22.05, 23.21, 
 20.12, 22.73, 21.88, 23.33, 24.76, 23.5, 22.06, 22.01, 
  20.65, 
 21.54, 19.9, 21.67, 21.84, 18.82, 17.99, 21.41, 23.53, 
 23.39, 
 25.75, 22.62, 22.25, 21.81, 16.81, 20.42, 12.08, 12.36, 
  15.31, 
 14.14, 15.48, 15.18, 14.19, 12.09, 12.39, 12.34, 12.61, 
 10.79, 
 10.53, 11.29, 9.92, 9.79, 10.86, 10.98, 10.58, 12.54, 
 12.52, 
 12.25, 6.38, 0.91, 5.24, 6.56, 5.72, 4.55, 4.99, 2.88, 
 0.99, 
 1.03, 1.57, 2.07, 2.3, 2.22, 2.11, 2.21, 2.29, 14.97, 
 16.31, 
 17.52, 7.45, 12.18, 15.82, 11.79, 14.45, 10.95, 13.62, 
 16.28, 
 11.42, 16.13, 15.09, 17.28, 14.43, 11.7, 16.06, 17.66, 
  16.33, 
 17.79, 18.58, 19.41, 19.8, 21.63, 21.35, 17.81, 17.56, 
 19.37, 
  21.27, 23.26, 23.67, 22.64, 21.85, 24.81, 22.36, 
  24.72, 23.87, 
23.67, 22.01, 19.23, 19.92, 21.99, 23.6, 24.9, 24.46, 
22.22, 
23.95, 24.81, 23.88, 22.98, 24.47, 26.09, 25.97, 25.82, 
26.24, 
25.09, 22, 16.91, 21.35, 25.32, 25.76, 26.38, 25.78, 
25.77, 25.15, 
26.29, 26.22, 24.59, 18.26, 18.91, 21.57, 21.37, 21.29, 
23.96, 
24.85, 21.02, 23.05, 22.69, 23.9, 25.24, 25.4, 23.19, 
22.8, 22.08, 
21.86, 13.82, 22.05, 23.21, 20.12, 22.73, 21.88, 23.33, 
24.76, 
23.5, 22.06, 22.01, 20.65, 21.54, 19.9, 21.67, 21.84, 
18.82, 
17.99, 21.41, 23.53, 23.39, 25.75, 22.62, 22.25, 21.81, 
16.81, 
20.42, 12.08, 12.36, 15.31, 14.14, 15.48, 15.18, 14.19, 
12.09, 
12.39, 12.34, 12.61, 10.79, 10.53, 11.29, 9.92, 9.79, 
 10.86, 
10.98, 10.58, 12.54, 12.52, 12.25, 6.38, 0.91, 5.24, 
6.56, 5.72, 
4.55, 4.99, 2.88, 0.99, 1.03, 1.57, 2.07, 2.3, 2.22, 
 2.11, 2.21, 
 2.29, 14.97, 16.31, 17.52, 7.45, 12.18, 15.82, 11.79, 
14.45, 
 10.95, 13.62, 16.28, 11.42, 16.13, 15.09, 17.28, 14.43, 
 11.7, 
 16.06, 17.66, 16.33, 17.79, 18.58, 19.41, 19.8, 21.63, 
 21.35, 
 17.81, 17.56, 19.37, 21.27, 23.26, 23.67, 22.64, 21.85, 
 24.81, 
 22.36, 24.72, 23.87, 23.67, 22.01, 19.23, 19.92, 21.99, 
 23.6, 
 24.9, 24.46, 22.22, 23.95, 24.81, 23.88, 22.98, 24.47, 
 26.09, 
 25.97, 25.82, 26.24, 25.09, 22, 16.91, 21.35, 25.32, 
 25.76, 26.38, 
 25.78, 25.77, 25.15, 26.29, 26.22, 24.59, 18.26, 18.91, 
 21.57, 
 21.37, 21.29, 23.96, 24.85, 21.02, 23.05, 22.69, 23.9, 
 25.24, 
 25.4, 23.19, 22.8, 22.08, 21.86, 13.82, 22.05, 23.21, 
 20.12, 
 22.73, 21.88, 23.33, 24.76, 23.5, 22.06, 22.01, 20.65, 
 21.54, 
 19.9, 21.67, 21.84, 18.82, 17.99, 21.41, 23.53, 23.39, 
 25.75, 
 22.62, 22.25, 21.81, 16.81, 20.42, 12.08, 12.36, 15.31, 
 14.14, 
 15.48, 15.18, 14.19, 12.09, 12.39, 12.34, 12.61, 10.79, 
 10.53, 
 11.29, 9.92, 9.79, 10.86, 10.98, 10.58, 12.54, 12.52, 
 12.25, 
 6.38, 0.91, 5.24, 6.56, 5.72, 4.55, 4.99, 2.88, 0.99, 
 1.03, 1.57, 
 2.07, 2.3, 2.22, 2.11, 2.21, 2.29)), class = 
 "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -456L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a `ddply()` or a `cast()` solution, but using `tidyverse` and `reshape2` you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Date, Independent_Variable) %>%
 summarise(Independent_Value = mean(Independent_Value)) %>%
 mutate(Independent_Variable = paste(Independent_Variable, "IV", sep = "_")) %>%
 dcast(Date~Independent_Variable, value.var = "Independent_Value") %>%
 arrange(factor(Date, levels = month.name)) %>%
 left_join(df %>%
 group_by(Date, Independent_Variable) %>%
 summarise(Sapflow = mean(Sapflow)) %>%
 mutate(Independent_Variable = paste(Independent_Variable, "Sapflow", sep = "_")) %>%
 dcast(Date~Independent_Variable, value.var = "Sapflow") %>%
 arrange(factor(Date, levels = month.name)),
 by = c("Date" = "Date"))

       Date Humidity_IV Radiation_IV Temperature_IV Humidity_Sapflow
1      June    17.60733     263.6733       70.56133        16.067000
2      July    21.80065     270.9065       61.33065        23.356774
3    August    18.38968     178.9806       71.73355        22.941613
4 September    14.82200     152.2333       72.21367        19.309333
5   October    11.34867      93.6000       81.74300         6.700667
  Radiation_Sapflow Temperature_Sapflow
1         16.067000           16.067000
2         23.356774           23.356774
3         22.941613           22.941613
4         19.309333           19.309333
5          6.700667            6.700667
```

First, it is grouping by "Date" and "Independent_Variable" and summarising "Independent_Value". Second, it is adding "_IV" to the values in Independent_Variable. Third, it is reshaping the data and arranging according the real order of months. Fourth, it is doing the first three steps for "Sapflow". Finally, it is merging the two.

Or by using just `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Date, Independent_Variable) %>% #Grouping
 summarise_all(funs(mean = mean(.))) %>% #Summarising all variables and adding "_mean" to the new variables
 arrange(factor(Date, levels = month.name)) #Arranging according the real order of months

   Date      Independent_Variable Independent_Value_mean Sapflow_mean
   <fct>     <fct>                                 <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 June      Humidity                               17.6        16.1 
 2 June      Radiation                             264.         16.1 
 3 June      Temperature                            70.6        16.1 
 4 July      Humidity                               21.8        23.4 
 5 July      Radiation                             271.         23.4 
 6 July      Temperature                            61.3        23.4
```

Comment: Thank you tmfmnk, your feedback is amazing. I have not had much experience with this function "%>%" (I assume it means 'equivalent') as I usually use "<-". After I have run your code, could I please ask how I could turn the summarised results into two new data frames. For instance, I would usually use "Sapflow_summarised<-data.frame(Sapflow_new). Your advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: `%>%` is called the "pipe" operator. It basically forwards a value or an expression from one line to the next one. You can select the relevant variables with `dplyr::select()` and then assign the results to a new df with `df <- df %>%
 group_by(Date, Independent_Variable) ...`.